# How can I look up a valid label name for use as declared service in IBM Bluemix manifest.yml

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Is there a valid list of label names for the "declared services" (https://github.com/IBM/watson-calorie-counter/blob/master/manifest.yml#L4) that can be used in a bluemix deployment documented somewhere?

This blog post describes how to get the label name for a specific service with the UI: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/01/deploy-to-bluemix-button-example/ -- But I was hoping there was a single source of truth documented somewhere, or I could find the information programmatically with the cf or bx CLIs.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the documentation on how the `declared-services` section work. It is an IBM extension to regular Cloud Foundry manifest files. [The extension is described in the IBM Cloud documentation for Continuous Delivery](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/deploy_button.html#deploy-button). That section also has details on how to look up the service names, labels:

> Declared services, a manifest extension which creates or looks for the
>   required or optional services that are expected to be set up before
>   the app is deployed, such as a data cache service. You can find a list
>   of the eligible Bluemix services, labels, and plans by using the CF
>   Command Line Interface command `cf marketplace` or by browsing the Bluemix catalog.

So you would look up how a service is named and what plans are offered.